# Chrome Extension Code To Toggle My Extension On & Off In Popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am working on building my first chrome extension and I got the thing nearly finished! However I have become stuck at the last part which is creating a simple html toggle to disable the extension temporarily. Basically, it functions like an ad blocker but rather than block ads it blocks websites and redirects them to a specific URL.

Here is the code I am using to attempt to do that but for some reason it will toggle Enable Disable but it does not turn off the redirect. The functionality of the app works perfectly now I just want to be able to turn it on and off.

**manifest.json**

```
 {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Purge",
    "description": "Why Use Anything But Google?",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128":"icon_128.png"},
    "browser_action": {"default icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"},
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://*/", "https://*/"],
    "background": {"scripts": ["blocked_domains.js", "background.js"]}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="toggle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>PURGE!</h3>
    <input type="button" id="toggle_button" value="Disable" />
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
var enabled = true;
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(info) {
      var url = "https://www.google.com/";
      return {redirectUrl: url};
    },
    {urls: blocked_domains},
    ["blocking"]);
```

**toggle.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    function updateLabel() {
        var enabled = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().enabled;
        document.getElementById('toggle_button').value = enabled ? "Disable" : "Enable";
    }
    document.getElementById('toggle_button').onclick = function () {
        var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
        background.enabled = !background.enabled;
        updateLabel();
    };
    updateLabel();
}
```

Comment: You never check the variable `enabled` in background.js

Comment: I have a couple of notes.  I'd be consistent with your variables.  Using `background.enabled` is a better option for both cases. Also, I'd use Standard Javascript formatting so it's more legible.  There's also a `--fix` flag in the cli so it will auto-format your files.  https://standardjs.com/

Comment: It's best to remove the listener when disabling. You'll need a named function for that, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're toggling the boolean `enabled` and the button along with it, but you still redirect regardless of the value.

Inside `onBeforeRequest` listener, check if the value of `enabled` is `true` of `false` before deciding to redirect:

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(info) {
      if(!enabled)                                           // if the extension is not enabled
        return { cancel: false };                            // don't cancel or redirect

      var url = "https://www.google.com/";
      return { redirectUrl: url };
    },
    {urls: blocked_domains},
    ["blocking"]);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! Thank you also for giving information as to why it didn't work for future learning! :)